# different eigenvalues and different eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

By book says:

- theorem 1:  if *all* eigevalues are different, then the eigenvectors are independent.
- theorem 2: if we have *pairwise* different eigenvalues, then the eigenvectors are independent.

Of course, the can exist in harmony; there is no contradiction between them since the latter is a stronger theorem.

But what I do not get is:

- why bother with telling me theorem 1 at all?
- I do not get what "pairwise" mean. Is it that $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_{i+k}$ must me different for $k=1$ but can be equal for all other $k$? (If $k>0$ of course.)

Comment: As for "pairwise", it always refers to all pairs of distinct members, not just adjacent pairs. Here it means $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ whenever $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 1):

Both theorems are badly formulated, especially theorem 1 which is just wrong. Whether or not there are other eigenvalues (and in particular if all are different), for each eigenvector $v$ one has $v$ and $2v$ are both eigenvectors, and the are linearly dependent.

Theorem $2$ should read: if one has a family of eigenvectors, all for different eigenvalues (so pairwise they are always for distinct eigenvalues), then the family is linearly independent. A statement that I like a bit more, and which expresses the same fact, is that for any list of distinct eigenvalues, the sum of the eigenspaces for those eigenvalues is a direct sum. It is equivalent because on one hand any family of nonzero vectors taken from the successive components of a direct sum are linearly independent, and on the other hand if  $v_1+\cdots+v_k=0$ for some vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ taken from the eigenspaces for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$, but not all $v_i$ are individually zero (which would happen if the sum of eigenspaces were not a direct sum), then the fact that the nonzero $v_i$ add up to $0$ would establish a linear dependence between eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues, which is not possible.

As for theorem 1, what it probably wanted to say is that if an operator on an $n$-dimensional space has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then any choice of eigenvectors for those $n$ eigenvalues gives a linearly independent family (and for dimension reasons a basis of the space). This is a straightforward consequence of the more general theorem 2, but considered to be of special interest (as in this situation it allows the operator to be diagonalised).

Answer (score 0):

What theorem 2 means is the following.  Suppose $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ are eigenvectors for eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ respectively, and all the $\lambda_i$ are distinct.  Then $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ are linearly independent.  This is different from theorem 1, in that not *all* eigenvalues are required to be distinct, just these $k$ eigenvalues.

I can't say why the book bothers with theorem 1.  Sometimes it's a good pedagogical strategy to prove a special case before proving the more general result, because the special case has a proof that is particularly instructive, or provides some insight or motivation.  I don't think that's the case here though.